# How to connect unbalanced output to balanced input?

Tags: audio-recording, home-studio, preamp

I would like to connected my bass guitar, which has an unbalanced tele output, to a preamp/mixer with balanced XLR inputs. Currently, I simply have an unbalanced cable with a tele male connector on one side and a XLR male connector on the other side. This works but seems to produce a lot of noise, noise not present if I connected the bass to a guitar amplifier (which has an unbalanced input). My guess is therefore that the noise is because I'm connecting my unbalanced output to a balanced input in the "wrong way" (I have tested all inputs on the mixer and is always the same noise).

What is the best way to make this connection? Should I use some sort of special cable? Use an intermediate preamp of some sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [direct box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_box) to change the unbalanced signal to a balanced signal.  You would plug your bass into the box and then plug the output of the box into a mixer.

[image]

There are two types; active and passive.  The passive box simply translates the signal and may have a switch to eliminate [ground loops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_loop_%28electricity%29) (thus removing the buzzing sound ).  The active box contains a preamp and will require some power source such as a battery or AC adapter.  I have an [active direct box](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000CCSWQA) which is stereo and can also use [phantom power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phantom_power).

As @leftaroundabout pointed out in his comment, you will probably need an active direct box for your bass.

Comment: This is the usual solution. Note that a passive DI has a too-low impedance to be used properly with passive bass/guitar pickups, so unless the bass itself is active the DI needs to be.

Comment: Good point.  I'll add that to the answer.